# Querying database using Scala console in Java Play

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm new to Play and I'm trying to test its shell (and Scala console) to query values from the database.
I'm using Play 2.4.3 and H2 (database)

From here: https://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/play-framework-2-quicktip-interactively-play-with-your-application-from-the-scala-console/
and here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4593
So far I've tried without success:

To get into the console

```
./activator shell
```

And then

```
console
```

Once I'm in the Scala console, I do:

```
import play.api._
val env = Environment(new java.io.File("."), this.getClass.getClassLoader, Mode.Dev)
val context = ApplicationLoader.createContext(env)
val loader = ApplicationLoader(context)
val app = loader.load(context)
Play.start(app)
import Play.current
```

I've got models called Question and Choice, so I import them doing:

```
import models._
```

(Also tried, models.Question and other combinations). Then when I try to query it by doing (and similar variants):

```
val questions = Question.all()
```

I get the error

```
<console>:8: error: value all is not a member of object models.Question
   val questions = Question.all()
                            ^
```

As a reference, you can find my Question model below:

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;
import play.data.format.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity
public class Question extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String question_text;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date pub_date = new Date();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question")
    public List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I've, in theory added, this scheme into the database using the activator run command (which offered me the script to update the DB). I'm using H2, file-based.

Also, I tried adding a new question

```
val questions = models.Question(1, "is this a question", format.parse("21-03-2011"))
```

Where format is:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

and I get the error:

```
   <console>:8: error: object models.Question is not a value
       val questions = models.Question(1, "is this a question", format.parse("21-03-2011"))
```

The question is:
So, how do I add values and query them back using the Scala console?

EDITED:
Just in case, you can add items as shown in the accepted answer and you can save them into the db using .save() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing Java and Scala classes, and the way to use both.

> val questions = Question.all()

This can't work because `Question` class does not have any static method called `all` (that method belongs to Mode.Finder). So you will have to create a finder in your class and maybe create those methods:

```
public class Question extends Model {
    // (...)
    public static final Finder<Integer, Question> find =
                                            new Finder<>(Question.class);

    public static List<Question> all() {
        return find.all();  
    }

}

val questions = Question.all
// or
val questions = Question.find.all
```

You can find more info in the [Model.Finder documentation](http://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/Model.Finder.html).

> val questions = models.Question(1, "is this a question", format.parse("21-03-2011"))

This syntax would only work out of the box if `Question` was a Scala case class.
Again you will have to use `new`, and if you don't want to specify each parameter after, implement a new constructor with the parameters you want to use:

```
val question = new Question
question.id = 1
question.question_text = "is this a question"
// (...)
```

Comment: I'm able to create a question with that method 
(scala> question res2: models.Question = models.Question@299f54ed) but I still can't query the db. Is there any other way to achieve it? The error is still:

scala> val questions = (new Question).all
<console>:14: error: value all is not a member of models.Question
       val questions = (new Question).all

Comment: @zom-pro Sorry you are right. You need to implement a finder. I've edited the answer with that information.

Comment: I  can query the DB now but I can't insert new values into it. I've the feeling, I need to have an "insert" property (as I needed a find one for querying). Do you know where can I find out the correct syntax for it?

Comment: Figured it out, you can do question.save()